# php-mode indents anonymous function incorrectly

Tags: indentation, php-mode

I have the latest Emacs and php-mode setup and this code does not get indented correctly

```php
$app->group('/route', function () use ($app) {
    echo 'hello';
});
```

Instead it looks like this

```php
$app->group('/route', function () use ($app) {
        echo 'hello';
    });
```

Note both the last line and that it indents the `echo` with 8 spaces instead of 4.

I've tried <kbd>M-x</kbd> `php-enable-psr2-coding-style` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Probably open a bug against `php-mode` rather than asking a question here?

Comment: Note though that PHP Mode is currently unmaintained. You'll probably not see this bug fixed unless you fix it yourself.

Comment: @lunaryorn Do you have any other suggestion for coding in PHP?

Comment: @Oskar No, I do not write PHP on a regular basis, and if I had to I'd buy PHPStorm.  But I doubt that there's any other PHP Mode for Emacs…

Comment: a php-mode fork is under current development, and is available (as php-mode) from  melpa: https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis That is the one I'm using.

Comment: I see you've opened an issue, and it's still open. great! (well, not "solved!" great, but "not-a-dead-end" great.)

Comment: @MichaelPaulukonis That is the very PHP Mode is spoke of.  “Unmaintained” might have been to harsh, but it's maintainer does not actively work on it anymore.  From the [README](https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode#status): “PHP Mode is not dead. However, I will no longer be contributing my own features because my time is taken up my game development that I am doing.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `php-mode` you can try `web-mode`. It supports php very well and  seemed to indent correctly your example.

**Edit:**
In order to make flycheck parses php, add the following to your web-mode-hook:

```
(flycheck-mode 1)
(flycheck-add-mode 'php 'web-mode)
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that I can't use [Flycheck](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck) in web-mode

Comment: I'll try when I get home but I think flycheck is major mode independent.

Comment: I edited the answer. Please try if it works